# Creating save point through CX-oracle?

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I want to implement savepoint and rollback feature in my current Data Layer.

I am using Python and cx-oracle for connection.

I see the rollback feature in cx-oracle but I cannot seem to figure out how to use savepoint here. Is it a feature to be used by cx-oracle externally i.e. there is a way to create a savepoint or is it implemented within the sql statements?

So if I have a sql file as:

```
Insert into .........
Savepoint insert_1
```

Is that the correct way to do that? Or, can i do it in my python script for every command (I have 4 commands in my python script for insert,delete,update and select).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SAVEPOINT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SAVEPOINT.html#GUID-78EEA746-0021-42E8-9971-3BA6DFFEE794) SQL command, as in the following:

```
cursor.execute("insert into ...")
cursor.execute("SAVEPOINT insert_1")
```